# Keyboard fail on USB HUB connected. After keyboard reconnect everything fine

Tags: keyboard, hardware-failure, usb-hub

Configuration:

Asrock Z270 Extreme 4 Mainboard. Connected devices to rear USB ports:

- USB 2.0 mouse (Steelseries Sensei)
- USB 2.0 keyboard (Steelseries M800)
- USB 3.0 HUB (TP-Link UH700) with 3 external HDD (Seagate Archive 8TBs)

The hub has a power switch, so its initial state is off. Keyboard, mouse are working, hub and HDDs are down. Hub and HDDs are powered from the PC's PSU
(Corsair RM1000i).

When I turn on the hub (HDDs are automatically turn on same time), the 
keyboard not respond anymore, only if I reconnect it. Mouse still working.
Tried in many combination (another port for keyboard, another for usb hub,
replaced with each others), but no success.

Has anyone have any idea how to fix this issue? The workstation in fix 
position, hard to reach the connectors, so I want to solve this before 
I kill the sockets.
sockets.

Comment: Test it perhaps with only one connected HDD. Are you using the latest firmware for the M800?

Comment: You are writing "Hub and HDDs are powered from the PC's PSU" - hopeful this is only the case until you power on the hub (the hub has it's own power supply and/or the HDDs have it's own power supply). If not this your problem. 3 HDDs can't be powered using one USB port (the one on the PC the hub is connected to).

Comment: Latest firmware on M800. With 1-2 HDD working in, but with 3rd HDD instant keyboard fail.
Robert: I mean RM1000i is a modular PSU, with lot of 12V connector, USB HUB and external hdd bays get the 12V from there, not from their adapters (PSU can support 70A+ on 12V lane, and quite better than cheap 12V adapters bundled with external bays/hubs/etc). I wrote the same psu to exclude ground loop and ac leakage as fault source.